# Add a membership to a person with an other than default company

Tags: civimember

i have a sporting company which does multiple sport departments each whith its own results  there are all part of the mothercompny called flevostar

so example you have Flevostar Basketball and FlevostarDart
i created 3 organisations in my contact list  Flevostar/Dart/Basketball

a new member is also created 
on the add membership page i would like to add a membership linking that new person to for instance Dart. Even though it appears that there is a drop down  i can only select default company  in this case Flevostar and a membership type.

ending up with that i have to absue the membership tpe to distinquish them so had to create MemberTypes  ACTMEM DART and AVTMEM Basketball
where as i would have liked to have new member x is member of department(organisation)Dart  whith type Member

is this any how to be achieved?

best regards

leon

ok  maybe i am not clear in my problem description. i use the backend for creating initial relation ships between the member and the department.  example: i have John as contact Basketball as organisation and flevostar as default.  now i go to johns personal sumary and click on memberships (initial they ar counted as 0) and i want to ad a membership.  Memberships tupes are  LID basketball  connected to Basketbal organisation and Lid Flevostar connected to flevostar organisation.  so in the memberships sumary i want to add johns membership to the basketball organisation with type Lid basketball.  However i can not select the organisatiobn Basketball in the drop down hence i can not link Lid basketball type to John  i hope this makes sense now

Comment: I don't think it's an abuse, to me that looks like just how it works. For one membership type to have a choice of chapters (or even for it to be able to cover multiple chapters?) this is a feature that would have to be added.

Comment: Hi Leon, if I understand correctly, when assigning a membership, you want to have a choice of a department that membership is for? As DaveFF mentioned, you will need to set up separate membership type for each department - a membership type can be associated with one organization (or department/chapter) only.

Comment: ok   i created serveral memberships and departments  i linked the membership types per department  now  still a new member should be able toselect the organization and membership type right?  fact is that the drop down for organisation only displays default organisation. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: seems there is some confusion here. on the public membership form/page there should not be a drop down for 'organisation' there should simply be the Membership Types assuming you added them via the Member tab of the Contribution page

Comment: ok  maybe i am not clear in my problem description. i use the backend for creating initial relation ships between the member and the department.

Answer (score 2):

This was too long to be a comment.

Are these people joining up for themselves on your public web pages, or are they being signed up as members by office staff using the "back office" pages?

Also a person has to choose the correct membership type to begin with. If a person is already a member of your default organisation then they will have to join again as a member of a different organisation.

Have you read the Membership section of our User and Admin guide, in particular the chapters [online membership and sign up](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/membership/online-membership-sign-up/), [manual entry of memberships](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/membership/manual-entry-of-memberships/) and [membership price sets](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/membership/membership-pricesets/)